termios.TIOCSTI when sudo
I have a problem when I want to fake an input for the next bash prompt, the following code is running correctly :
import fcntl
import termios
with open("/dev/stdout", 'w') as fd:
    for c in "Salut!!":
        fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, c)

My problem is when I run this on sudo (not sudo su), even if I fetch the right tty for the original user, it doesn't write in the input when sudo quit, how can this works ?


What is the purpose of the who|grep|awk, as opposed to just calling ioctl on stdout? 2) What kernel version are you running (uname -r)? 3) What is the result of either zgrep TIOC /proc/config.gz or grep TIOC /boot/config-*? 4) What is the result of sysctl dev.tty?


@user1686 I'm using who|grep|awk to get the exact tty for the user running, simply doing /dev/stdout is working for no-sudo, but isn't working when I sudo the command. My OS is RHEL 8.9 so kernel 4.18.0-513.18.1. The rest of your command suggestions are not working for me :/

The reason I'm asking is that the whole process looks like the opposite of exact to me – the inaccurate grepping aside, a user could have many ttys – one for each terminal, each tab, etc (and on my laptop with GNOME on it, the 1st line would say "seat0" in place of a tty...) Do you mean that on your system, the commands tty and sudo tty return different results?

@user1686 yes I know that a single user can open many tty as he wants, I will need to find a better solution to get the true one who runned sudo. Yes tty and sudo tty are not printing the same result :/

What exactly are you trying to achieve with this whole program, though? What is the purpose of injecting fake input to the user's tty, when the user can type it in already?

@user1686 My goal is to prefill the next bash prompt for the user, because my main program is a TUI and if he clicks on something particular, I want that what's printed is populate on the prompt. I hope you get it :) (I remove all subprocess because writing in /dev/stdout is working in no-sudo)

Sort of like tools such as fzf that people use for selecting files in shell commandline? If so, there are better ways to achieve that without relying on root-only features that practically have been removed from latest Linux already.

@user1686 Yes sort of fzf but without running the command I choosed, just prefill the command line. If you have some suggestions, i'm glad to hear that :)

I do in fact have suggestions – see https://github.com/grawity/dotfiles/blob/main/bash/fzf.sh; I have it bound to Alt-D/Alt-F using bash's internal functionality so that it works without root. (The whole thing is shell-specific, but I'm sure zsh and fish can support that in their own ways.)

@user1686 Thanks for your help, i'm a bit in trouble to analyse dotfiles and bash/zsh scripts haha, I put an issue on the git of cmatrix who use the same principle with termios but in C, I let u check : https://github.com/abishekvashok/cmatrix/issues/189
